# how to add digits in a long variable that will be converted to string?

Tags: java

i had this method:

```
public long getLastSequenceNumber();
```

it should return me:

1. 0
2. a number that should be like 34,60,103...
3. the maximum amount of 12 digits number (243265438564 for example).

What i want is when i get this number i want to convert it to a String and add the "0" that is missing in the front of number to get the 12 digits. if it comes with 12 digits then just convert to string.

Example:

1. if i get 45 then convert to "000000000045".
2. if i get 0 then convert to "000000000000".
3. if i get 834213238956l (12 digits) then just convert to
   "834213238956" (same number, but in String).

How i can do it in Java?

Comment: I think `String.format( "%012d", <long> )` will format a long value with 12 digits.  [Check the docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Comment: What do you want if the number passed in is 13 digits?

Comment: it will not pass 13 digits... String.format works very well, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to convert the number directly to a `String`.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("000000000000"); // 12 zeros
String s = df.format(x);
String fortyFive = df.format(45);
```

Alternatively, you can call [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) with a [`0` to indicate leading zeros and a `12` for the length](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

```
String s = String.format("%012d", x);
String fortyFive = String.format("%012d", 45);
```